# LDAP Authentication using DataSource configured in Weblogic

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi

I am aware of authenticating username/password by establishing JNDI Initialcontext with LDAP. That means authentication failed on error or success.

Wondering there is another means of using JNDI resource configured in Application Server and do Authenticate.

Please post me if there is any links.

Comment: What is actually your goal? A common pattern is also implemented with SPNEGO.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that "Foreign JNDI Providers" is the best suite to create LDAP Connection pool and use that from your business logic